# Bind different functions to different options in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in need to do such thing

```
<select>
  <option ng-sth="firstMethodToBeCalled()">Option 1</option>
  <option ng-sth="secondMethodToBeCalled()">Option 2</option>
<select>
```

Is there any way to do this?
I need this because i currently have this kind of code:

```
<select ng-model="someModel" ng-change="callThisFunction()">
  <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
  ...
  <option value="valueN">Option N</option>
</select>
```

And I want to add only two more options to this Select but calling different function. I can refactor it to call same wrapper function and determine which final function shall be called with some conditional logic but I am wondering if there is a possibility to assign different. I have been looking for this for some time and didn't come across any solution.

Comment: Can't you pass the ng-model value to the  callThisFunction() and determine the logic to be called based on the value.

Comment: Yes I can. But I would have to refactor few controllers/services that rely on this model to maintain clean code. Sure I will if nothing else will come across.

Comment: Look this http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/483/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **i'm afraid you can't**.

By the way, i would keep to have single function in ng-change and the put some logic inside it (and call your second function too from there), like this:

```
$scope.callThisFunction = function(){
   if(someModel == "baz")
      myFirstfunction();
   else
      mySecondFunction();
}
```

it's the cleanest solution in my opinion, and the most mantainable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! there is a way you can achieve this.Create a functions object with keys as your selected option which is your `ng-model` and value as a function aligned to it and performa ny action in it.

In your JS

```
$scope.functions ={
    "value1":function(){
        console.log("function for option 1 called");
    },"value2":function(){
        console.log("function for option 2  called");
    }
};
```

In your HTML

```
<select ng-model="someModel" ng-change="functions[someModel]()">
  <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
  ...
  <option value="valueN">Option N</option>
</select>
```

Call the functions object in your `ng-change` by passing the your `ng-model` which is selected option which will invoke corresponding function.